# Question about the minimal polynomial of an inseparable element in a field

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

Let $K/F$ be a field extension. The characteristic of F is prime $p$. Suppose $\beta \in K$
is an inseparable element of degree $p$, show the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ in $F$.

Comment: What have you treid?

Comment: I don't know how to use the condition to solve the problem